# Update a column using LOAD_FILE function

Tags: mysql

I have created a table lfile. The structure of table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `lfile` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

In the table I have 3 records:

```
select * from lfile;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | ravi  |
|  2 | kumar |
|  3 | ark   |
+----+-------+
```

Now I want to update 'ravi' with 'ravikumar' using LOAD_FILE.

```
  UPDATE lfile SET name=LOAD_FILE('/home/ravi/Desktop/t') WHERE id=1;
```

But it updates the name column with a NULL value.

```
mysql> select * from lfile;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | NULL  |
|  2 | kumar |
|  3 | ark   |
+----+-------+
```

Settings:

```
show variables like 'character_set_filesystem';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| character_set_filesystem | utf8  |
+--------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: The function [returns NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) when the file was not readable - check the privileges etc. Try `select LOAD_FILE('/home/ravi/Desktop/t'); show warnings;` to see what the function returns.

Comment: I gave full permission to file.select LOAD_FILE('/home/ravi/Desktop/t'); query returns NULL after changing permission also.show warnings; returns nothing.In file i have only one word 'kumar'.

Comment: Is the mysql on your local computer? What user do you use for mysql? Does it have the `FILE` privilege? Any apparmor/selinux or other things which might override user permissions?

Comment: Yes i am using MySQL server on my local machine.I am connecting mysql server with root user and file has full permission.

Answer (score 0):

> Now i want to update 'ravi' with 'ravikumar'

`LOAD FILE` loads an entire table, not one column, not one cell.

Instead,

```
UPDATE lfile
    SET name = 'ravikumar'
    WHERE name = 'ravi';
```

Comment: Hi Rick James I read load_file function from this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_ascii.yes i can update a column by using your query but i want to update from a file.

Comment: Rick James,load file is used to load data into a table but what  is the use case of LOAD_FILE function?

Comment: Your link is broken; you wanted [load_file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file).  Do you have a file with just one word ('ravikumar') on one line?  How do you know that that should replace `name` on the row with "ravi" ?

Comment: yes I have file with one word in line.

Comment: How do you know that that should replace name on the row with "ravi" ?

Comment: I got it from mysql website that's why I provided the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has a security protection to avoid accessing any files on the disk.
The root directory is defined as key in the section 'msqld' (in the file e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf)

```
[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = /var/lib/MyLocationOfTheFilesToLoad
```

Please avoid setting this to high in the directory structure (e.g. don't use: '/' or '/var' or '/etc' ).
It will allow to load and overwrite files you might want to protect or keep secret.

This setting is global, and it is valid for all users, scripts, procedures and instances by default.

After the database has reload the configuration (e.g. by restarting mysql) the following SQL command will work:

```
UPDATE `table` 
  SET `field` = Load_File( '/var/lib/MyLocationOfTheFilesToLoad/test.txt' )
  WHERE `ID` = 4711;
```

Or in your case:

```
[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = /home/ravi/Desktop
```

and

```
UPDATE `lfile` 
  SET `name` = LOAD_FILE('/home/ravi/Desktop/t') 
  WHERE `id` = 1;
```

Please use this privilege with care, the system may be **vulnerable** after changeing the config file.

On linux systems e.g. use a path like /var/local/*createdByYou/somewhere* in the conf, and create symbolic links there to your final location to protect scanning the entire system.